# Voltage sensitive compounds that undergo a conformational change?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In nature, the Ca/Na/K channels which consist of groups protein are often voltage sensitive and undergo conformational changes in response to voltages on the order of mV.

Are there any known classes of other simpler organic or inorganic compounds which also undergo rapid conformational changes in response to applied voltages?

Comment: http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2007/cs/b604484k#!divAbstract you might be interested in these. No time to summarise now - someone else feel free to use it.

Comment: bon. Thank you for the general site information.

Comment: orthocresol. Thank you for the interesting link. Had not considered the molecular machine aspect.